# Change Android Switch widget height programmatically

Tags: android, android-switch

I'm using the following code to programmatically create a switch:

```
Switch s = new Switch(mActivity);

s.setText(text);
s.setBackground(selectorDrawable);       
s.setTypeface(mFont);
s.setTextSize(mEntriesTextSize);
s.setTextSize(8);
s.setTag(command);
s.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
s.setPadding(mEntriesSidesPadding,
    mEntriesUpDownPadding, mEntriesSidesPadding,
    mEntriesUpDownPadding);
s.setChecked(on);

// attempted to change height here...

s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mOnCheckedListener);

mLayout.addView(s, mLayoutParams);
returnView = s;
```

How might I go about changing the height of the actual switch on screen (not the text height, the height of the ON/OFF switch itself)

I've tried

```
setMaxHeight(), setMinHeight(), setHeight()
```

but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try s.setMinimumHeight()

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
s.getLayoutParams().height = YOUR_HEIGHT;
```

(YOUR_HEIGHT is desired height in pixel)

If you're setting the height after the layout has already been 'laid out', make sure you call:

```
s.requestLayout()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution which worked best was:

```
            s.setSwitchMinWidth(x);
```

where `x` is your desired value. Took me a while to find this amongst said similar functions.